# Scrolling content right to left Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a page with a horizontal width of 4000px

How would i go about creating an event that starts as soon as the page loads and cycles from the far right to left of the page? I want to show all the content and get the user back to the start if you get me

Ideally coded in javascript but will accept CSS3 (if it can be done)

Thanks Guys,

DIM3NSION

Based on your responses i have tried to get this working, but with no avail.
Help much appreciated

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
   function start(){ 
   document.body.scrollTo(4000, 0); 
   var x=4000;
   var t= setInterval(function(){ x-=50
   if (x<=0){ clearInterval(t); document.body.scrollTo(0,0); return; } document.body.scrollTo(x, 0); }, 20) }
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably some errors in this code, since I'm typing it on my phone, but something like this should work. Just stick it in a window.onload function.

```
function start(){
   window.scrollTo(4000, 0); 
   var x=4000; 

   var t = setInterval(function(){ 
       x-=50; // or whatever 
       if (x<=0){ 
           clearInterval(t); 
           window.scrollTo(0,0); 
           return; 
       } 
       window.scrollTo(x, 0); 
   }, 20) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, see my edit. Its not working is there a problem with that code?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) does exactly what you need. [See it in action](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/). Combined with the `setTimeout` or `setInterval` function, you could easily achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would work for an entire page, but it could be slicker than using the built in browser scrollbars, and easier to set up, to boot: http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/

Comment: Thanks for your response, see my edit. Its not working is there a problem with that code?